# How to use C# to display pdf in onenote using com/interop api

Tags: c#, pdf, com, interop, onenote

I'm new to stack overflow, C# and onenote interop com api.  I'm trying to display a pdf file in onenote using C# and the onenote com/interop api (I'd rather not use the REST API).

I am able to display a link to a pdf file using the tag < InsertedFile pathSource="[myfilepath]" preferredName = "[myPreferredName]"> in conjunction with the UpdatePageContent function in the interop API, but this doesn't display the PDF.

I have been able to get my program to display an image in onenote using the following code to create the image tag

```
    private XElement createImageTag(Image image)
    {
        string OneNoteNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote";
        var img = new XElement(XName.Get("Image", OneNoteNamespace));
        var data = new XElement(XName.Get("Data", OneNoteNamespace));
        data.Value = this.toBase64(image);
        img.Add(data);
        return img;
    }

   private string toBase64(Image image)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            var binary = memoryStream.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(binary);
        }
    }
```

I tried altering this for a pdf instead of am image by converting a pdf to a byte array then converting it to base64 and assigning the result as data.Value in the createImageTag function but it did not result in a displayed pdf either (presumably because onenote was expecting an image and not a pdf).  I'd like to avoid using third party libraries or extensions to convert a pdf to an image if possible, and haven't found any other ways to convert a pdf to an image.

I used ONOMSpy to look for any other onenote/xml tags that might help me display a pdf in onenote, but didn't see others besides the Image and InsertedFile tags that looked like they were close to doing what I wanted.

so if you could help me either :
1) find an easy way to convert a pdf to an image using C# or
2) show me how to tell onenote to display the PDF

I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a page in front of me.  But did you try loading up a page with a pdf already inserted (with an image) and export the content xml?  curious what tags you see.

Comment: Yes I tried this several different ways using the ONOMspy software that basically is a tool that exports the xml from onenote pages.  The tags used differed depending on method of importing pdf to display (print to onenote vs insert file as printout).  However, they both seemed to rely on some combination of the image or InsertedFile tags.  Additionally they both seemed to reference the required data using an ID attribute that onenote manages like objectID or CallBackID neither of which I know how to interact with.

Comment: <one:OE creationTime="2016-10-25T23:07:31.000Z" lastModifiedTime="2016-10-25T23:07:31.000Z" objectID="{0E84DBD5-38FD-0821-15F2-1E5BD89AAE15}{38}{B0}" alignment="left">
        <one:InsertedFile pathCache="[file]" pathSource="[file" />
</one:OE>
 <one:Image format="png" isPrintOut="true" lastModifiedTime="2016-10-25T23:07:32.000Z" objectID="{0E84DBD5-38FD-0821-15F2-1E5BD89AAE15}{41}{B0}">
    <one:Position x="36.0" y="162" z="0" />
    <one:Size width="613" height="793" />
    <one:CallbackID callbackID="{0E84DBD5-38FD-0821-15F2-1E5BD89AAE15}{41}{B0}" />
 </one:Image>

Comment: the previous is the xml from a page where I inserted a pdf as prinout.  Sorry I can't get it to indent in the comment section.  I redacted the filepaths and deleted some of the position data so it would come under the number of allowed characters in comments